# View scope bean injecting application scope and modify app scope data. Bad practice?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, myfaces

I have a view scoped bean and based on the user input, it might need to change the values of the application scope bean for the entire app to use the new values. It seems to be a bad practice to change values of application scope bean in real time. The application bean loads all the values of support tables, with the admin part of my app, I want the admin users to be able to add things to the support tables and then everyone should be able to use the new values.

The problem I'm seeing is that the view bean gets a new instance of the injected managed property each time the page has to go back to the managed bean, I also see a similar problem when injecting session scope into view scope and changing values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate problems here.

Whether it is good practice to modify global application state via in-memory beans depends on the specifics of what you are doing, how much state there is, how its going to be persisted, whether the application is in a clustered environment, etc.

Stack Overflow is unsuited to doing a detailed architectural review.

> The problem I'm seeing is that the view bean gets a new instance of the injected managed property each time the page has to go back to the managed bean, I also see a similar problem when injecting session scope into view scope and changing values.

This does not sound right at all. You might see new instances (proxied beans) if you're using [CDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/partcdi.htm#GJBNR) but you mention managed properties so I guess not. Application scoped beans are placed into the [application map](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getApplicationMap%28%29) and remain there until the application is stopped.

So, there is something wrong with your application logic or you have omitted some relevant detail about your software stack or environment.